# Why is a "-1" appearing on right side of my zsh Terminal prompt?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, prompt

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay3sp.png)

I recently switched over from bash to zsh for my Terminal shell, however after using it for about a week this "-1" started appearing on the right hand side of my window. It get's printed with every new prompt. I'm really at a loss here, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: the answer depends on how you configured your prompt :) provide the output of $PROMPT and $RPROMT

Comment: Remember quoting, e.g.: `echo "$RPROMPT"`.

Comment: echo "$PROMPT" gave me:
`$(rb_prompt) in $(directory_name) $(git_dirty)$(need_push)`

and echo "$RPROMPT" is: `%{%}-1%{%}`

Comment: and the -1 is _always_ there? reference for prompt-expansion is here, http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html